# Puertos en uso para tomcat en netbeans...identifica a los puertos en uso

Tags: netbeans, spring-boot, tomcat

gracias por sus respuestas cree un proyecto en spring boot, en netbeans pero al compilar me sale este error.....Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.....ya cambie por otros puerto sale el mismo error, deshabilite el firewall del sistemas, le puse el valor 0 al puerto para que tome cualquier puerto libre y no termina de compilar, por favor si a alguien le paso este problema...